# c# invoking delegate function throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, nullreferenceexception

I have two forms, a FormMain, and a FormInputTagName. The FormMain uses FormInputTagName as a dialog to get a string from the user.
For this I've declared a delegate in FormInputTagName, here's the code:

```
public partial class FormInputTagName : Form
{
    public delegate void ResultDelegate(string tagName);

    public ResultDelegate _resultDelegate;

    public void InputTagName(ResultDelegate resultDelegate)
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        _resultDelegate = resultDelegate;
    }

    private void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        _resultDelegate(textBoxElementTagName.Text);
    }
}
```

Just in case, _resultDelegate is public, but it doesn't solve the problem.

In the FormMain, I have a method, with the signature as delegate declares:

```
    public void AddElement(string tagName)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tagName);
    }
```

And a code (also in FormMain), that calls FormInputTagName passing AddElement as a delegate instance to it:

```
    private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormInputTagName inputForm = new FormInputTagName();
        inputForm.InputTagName(new FormInputTagName.ResultDelegate(AddElement));
    }
```

And when I run the program and type some text into textBoxElementTagName and click Ok button, it throws System.NullReferenceException at line

```
_resultDelegate(textBoxElementTagName.Text);
```

What can be a cause? Can it be that I call delegate in synchronous manner and should I call it using BeginInvoke / EndInvoke ?
And one more thing - if I do not save delegate into a class member _resultDelegate, but call it immediately, like that

```
public void InputTagName(ResultDelegate resultDelegate)
{
    this.ShowDialog();
    resultDelegate("qwer");
}
```

it works fine and calls AddElement function.

Comment: Where is `Ok_Click` called? Note that you're only assigning `_resultDelegate` *after* calling `ShowDialog`, so if it's trying to use `_resultDelegate` during `ShowDialog`, that could be the issue.

Comment: Yup as Jon said you are opening the dialog prior to setting the delegate. This is most likely your issue.

Comment: OMG! You are right, I changed it so that it first saves resultDelegate and then shows a dialog and it works fine! I have stupidly thought that showDialog is asynchronous and doesn't stop execution. Thank you very much!